# Python Password Program

Tags: python, python-2.7, passwords

I'm a beginner programmer and thought it would be cool to create a program to loop through "all" possible passwords. 
On a scale of 1-10, how efficient would you rate the following "hacking program?" Is there any way to make the following code more efficient? Any algorithms or tricks that you may know of?

I've considered moving 'e' and more common letters to the beginning of my character array since those letters are used more commonly.

```
import sys

password = raw_input("Enter a password: ")

characters = []
lower = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
upper = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
number = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
symbol = ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","+","-","="]

#Creates array with most keyboard characters
for i in range(len(lower)):
    characters.append(lower[i])
for i in range(len(upper)):
    characters.append(upper[i])
for i in range(len(number)):
    characters.append(number[i])
for i in range(len(symbol)):
    characters.append(symbol[i])

found = False

#For 1 character passwords
for a in range(len(characters)):
    if (characters[a] == password):
        print (characters[a])
        found = True
if (found):
    sys.exit()

#For 2 character passwords
for a in range(len(characters)):
    for b in range(len(characters)):
        if (characters[a] + characters[b] == password):
            print (characters[a] + characters[b])
            found = True
if (found):
    sys.exit()

for a in range(len(characters)):
    for b in range(len(characters)):
        for c in range(len(characters)):
            if (characters[a] + characters[b] + characters[c] == password):
                print (characters[a] + characters[b] + characters[c])
                found = True
if (found):
    sys.exit()

for a in range(len(characters)):
    for b in range(len(characters)):
        for c in range(len(characters)):
            for d in range(len(characters)):
                if (characters[a] + characters[b] + characters[c] + characters[d] == password):
                    print (characters[a] + characters[b] + characters[c] + characters[d])
                    found = True
if (found):
    sys.exit()

for a in range(len(characters)):
    for b in range(len(characters)):
        for c in range(len(characters)):
            for d in range(len(characters)):
                for e in range(len(characters)):
                    if (characters[a] + characters[b] + characters[c] + characters[d] + characters[e] == password):
                        print (characters[a] + characters[b] + characters[c] + characters[d] + characters[e])
                        found = True
if (found):
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you didn't have to type all those symbols

```
>>> import string
>>> string.uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> string.lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> string.digits
'0123456789'
>>>
```

so you can do:

```
lower = string.lowercase
```

and so forth

This can go away:

```
#Creates array with most keyboard characters
for i in range(len(lower)):
    characters.append(lower[i])
for i in range(len(upper)):
    characters.append(upper[i])
for i in range(len(number)):
    characters.append(number[i])
for i in range(len(symbol)):
    characters.append(symbol[i])
```

and be replaced with:

```
characters = "".join(upper, lower, number, symbol)
```

This can be simplified:

```
#For 1 character passwords
for a in range(len(characters)):
    if (characters[a] == password):
        print (characters[a])
        found = True
if (found):
    sys.exit()
```

to:

```
for a in characters:
    print a
    sys.exit()
```

The multi-character checks will need to loop, but try  writing the loops like I showed in the single character code above

Answer (score 1):

In this regard, it is mandatory to mention [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). 
This answer doesn't provide an answer to "this is why your programming is efficient or not", but it's a reminder that if you quickly want a setup / script with which you can bruteforce something, there's a nice lib.

```
import itertools
import string

for guess in itertools.product(string.lowercase, repeat=10): 
     password = ''.join(guess) #put the array elements together
     print password
```

`itertools.product` gives you all possible combinations (cartesian cross product) for a given array of elements, in this case, the lowercase alpahabet and you have the code that generates all passwords of arbitrary length for you in effectively 3 lines of code.

Now go rewrite that `repeat=10` into a variable expression and do a `for` loop from `1` to whatever password length you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient code would be

```
password = raw_input("Enter a password: ")
guess = password
print guess
```

:)

Alright jokes aside, your solution is a simple brute force attack to find the password and if we have no additional information about the password (besides what the legal alphabet is) then a brute force attack is the best possible attack (in terms of algorithmic complexity).

But your code has scope for improvements in implementation.

Instead of

```
for i in range(len(lower)):
  characters.append(lower[i])
for i in range(len(upper)):
  characters.append(upper[i])
for i in range(len(number)):
  characters.append(number[i])
for i in range(len(symbol)):
  characters.append(symbol[i])
```

Do this

```
characters = lower + upper + number + symbol
```

And instead of having so many cases to handle what the password could be, let's use some Math to make things much much simpler to implement :)

Note that if the size of that characters list is n, and if the length of the password is l, then using some basic Discrete Math/Combinatorics, there are n^l possible combinations that we can make using the given alphabet set. We can simply map each and every combination of characters to a single number that is expressed in base n. eg If n = 2 and the alphabet comprises of just 'a' and 'b', then the number string 10 in base 2 will correspond to the string "ba". Similalry the string 00100 will coresspond to "aabaa"

So our task reduces to generating all possible strings.

This can be done via recursion (which has a little bit of overhead but it reduces the load on implementation)

```
def recurse(s, l, n):
    if n == l:
        if s == password: return True
        return False:
    for c in characters:
        if recurse(s + c, l, n+1) == True: return True:
    return False



 recurse("", len(password), 0)
```